# split existing solr collection over more nodes

Tags: solr, nodes, sharding

I am using Solr 4.10
Initially I had a collection with indexed documents on only one node, but now I have added an additional node.
Is it possible to split my existing index over both the nodes without having to recreate the collection and reindex everything?

I tried using the splitshard command from the collections api but that just split my collection into 2 shards on the same node.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how this can work.

First split the collection into 2 shards on the same node. Then replicate one of the shards onto another node and delete the original shard.